# how can i put fontawesome icons in markdown ? (readme file that will be uploaded to github)

Tags: html, css, markdown, github-flavored-markdown, readme

I want to put some fontawesome icons in my readme to explain what they mean in my website but markdown doesnt allow css so is there a way I can overcome this?

This is where I got the [icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/crown?style=solid)

This would be the html `<i class="fas fa-crown"></i>`

This is the stylesheet link
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Simple, you can't!**

---

What you can do is download the image you want and include it, for example:

```
![fa-crown](fa-crown.svg)
```

or

```html
<img src="fa-crown.svg" width="50" height="50">
```

If you want to learn more: [GitHub Flavored Markdown Spec](https://github.github.com/gfm/)

---

**Update**

You can also use the FontAwesome images hosted on the [FontAwesome GitHub repo](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/6.x/svgs). Therefore you can use it like this:

```html
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/6.x/svgs/solid/crown.svg" width="50" height="50">
```

You will see this:

[image]

Comment: thank you, i didnt know you could download it so i went back and saw that you could.

Comment: thanks for this answer @abrahamcalf ... do you know how to specify icon colors when they are being used this way?

Comment: @abu You cannot easily change the color, but you can download the SVG image and edit it. I have created a gist to demonstrate it https://gist.github.com/abrahamcalf/bbd45c6a6e55dad4100512754454555b